# Mostrar Imagen 1 segundo y luego Quitarla 1 segundo y luego volverla a Mostrar setVisibility

Tags: android

Necesito mostrar una imagen por 1 segundo ya que paso 1 segundo tengo que ocultarla durante 1 segundo, y luego mostrar la siguiente imagen de la lista por 1 segundo y luego ocultarla por 1 segundo hasta recorrer todas las imagenes de la lista.

Mi problema es, que mi código solo me muestra la primer imagen y la siguientes no las muestra, las deja invisibles y recorre toda la lista, pero solo muestra la primera.

Codigo:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void showNextImage() {
    // loads the image at position currentPosition
    final Bits item = L.get(currentPosition);
    imageBit.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageBit.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));
        }
    },1000);

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       nameBit.setText(item.getbText());

                       imageBit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                   }
               },1000);
            currentPosition++; // updates the current position
            if (L.size() > currentPosition) { // more images to show?

                // loads the next image after some delay
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageBit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        showNextImage();
                    }
                }, 1000); // in millis, 1000 for one second delay

            }
}
```

Comment: Prueba esa solución planteada, si tiene errores de compilación o algo por el estilo, hazme saber, la edité mientras respondía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero intenta crear una lista de Bitmaps llamada `ItemsBitmap`, declarar `currentPosition` global y crear una variable para almacenar el `bitmap` global también:

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> ItemsBitmap;
public Bitmap bitmap;
public currentPosition = 0;
```

Ahora inicializa la lista con los bitmaps antes de llamar al método showImages:

```
ItemsBitmap = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < L.size(); i++){
   Bits item = L.get(i);
   ItemsBitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));
}
showImages();
```

Aqui el método:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void showImages() {
        bitmap = ItemsBitmap.get(currentPosition);
        imageBit.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
            boolean continuar = true; // Si quieres que se detenga, vuelve continuar false en algun momento
            int number = 0;
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(number % 2 != 0) {
                    if(number == 101)
                      number = -1; // esto hace que la bandera no crezca mucho
                    imageBit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    bitmap = ItemsBitmap.get(currentPosition);
                    imageBit.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    currentPosition++;
                    if (ItemsBitmap.size() == currentPosition) {
                        currentPosition = 0; // Esto hace que se vuelva a repetir la lista de Bitmaps
                    }
                    imageBit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                number++;
            }
            public void onFinish() {

                if (continuar) {
                    this.start();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Lo probé y me funciona perfecto, dejame saber si te funciona.

Comment: Si me funciono, con unas mejoras que le implemente para que mostrara un texto cuando la imagen esta oculta y viceversa. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Porque no simplemente creas dos métodos uno que haga invisible  y otro que haga visible, es decir al iniciar la actividad aparecerá la imagen por un segundo y este sera controlado por un Handler() y después que pase este tiempo el Handler() lanzara el método invisible que también incluirá un Handler() adentro que determinara cuando activar el método visible. Y para pasar de una imagen a otra te ofrezco un método que almacena las rutas de los archivos de un directorio en un List y que puede acceder a ellos por su posición incrementando el valor 0 que es el primero hasta el ultimo valor  Algo simple creo. 
Metodo:

```
private List <String> getSD()
{
 List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
String files1;
 File f = new File ("ruta");
 File[] files = f.listFiles ();

 for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)
 {
    File  file = files[i];


    Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
    it.add (file.getAbsolutePath());
 }
 return it;
}
```

Este devuelve el List y lo obtienes y usas asi:

```
   int valor=0;     
private void cambio(){
List <String> ImageList;

ImageList=getSD();
if(valor==ImageList.size()){
//no hay mas
}else{
valor++;
String ruta=ImageList.get(valor).toString();
imageBit.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(ruta));
//Usted agregue el resto.
}
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma quedo funcionando:

Gracias por tu ayuda :

> Andrespengineer

Declaraciones...

```
private int currentPosition = 0;
public ArrayList<Bitmap> ItemsBitmap;
public Bitmap bitmap;

public Bits items;
```

Inicializo:

```
ItemsBitmap = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < L.size(); i++){
        Bits item = L.get(i);
        ItemsBitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));

    }
    for (int x = 0; x < L.size(); x++){
        Bits item = L.get(x);
        nameBit.setText(item.getbText());
    }
    showImages();
```

Metodo:

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void showImages() {
    new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        boolean continuar = true; // Si quieres que se detenga, vuelve continuar false en algun momento
        int number = 0;
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if(number % 2 != 0) {
                if(number == 101)
                    number = -1; // esto hace que la bandera no crezca mucho
                imageBit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nameBit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                bitmap = ItemsBitmap.get(currentPosition);
                imageBit.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                items = L.get(currentPosition);
                nameBit.setText(items.getbText());
                currentPosition++;
                if (ItemsBitmap.size() == currentPosition) {
                    currentPosition = 0; // Esto hace que se vuelva a repetir la lista de Bitmaps
                }
                imageBit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (L.size() == currentPosition){
                    currentPosition = 0;
                }
                nameBit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            number++;
        }
        public void onFinish() {

            if (continuar) {
                this.start();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: No hay de qué, bienvenido